# How can I create a formula in Excel that uses DATES?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I subtract days from a cell that has dates?

For example, what's a formula that will take 3/2/2011 and return this value 2/28/2011?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have one cell that is formatted as a date (e.g. `3/2/11`) and subtract 2 from it, you will get `2/28/11`:
[image]

For example your formula would be

```
A1-2
```

Answer (score 1):

More generally, you can decompose a given date into YEAR(), MONTH(), and DAY() values, then recombine them via DATE().  For instance, to add six months and a day to A1

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1)+6, DAY(A1)+1 )
```